# Android java.lang.AbstractMethodError on requestLocationUpdates

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, abstractmethoderror

i get this error `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String)`

when i call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`. I saw another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638260/android-locationlistener-abstractmethoderror-on-onstatuschanged-and-onproviderd) where the answer was to override some methods i.e.

```
 @Override
public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {}
```

But the thing is i cannot override them anywhere in my project.

**I have simplified the code** in order to help the readers and instead of two classes i have one

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener  locationListener = location -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> showLoc());

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(v -> locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener));

    }
    private void showLoc(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 13);
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 13) {
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG Request Permissions ");
                    showLoc();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown at `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` and has something to do with library version.

And lastly this is my **build.gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: That might be a version conflict, i.e. you might be using a library that has an implementation of `LocationListener` but that isn't implementing that abstract method because it has been compiled using a different version of the Android SDK than you're running you app on atm.

Comment: Have a look here on what that `AbstractMethodError` generally means in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstractmethoderror

Comment: i have read the post. The thing is that if you see the link on the top of my question i mention another post where it says that there are some un-implemented methods. As the error suggests and the article from baeldung, it makes sense. 
But when i try to implement these methods i just cannot ! Nowhere in my two classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. After android 10(Q) you won't need lot's of the the **unimplemented methods** of `LocationListener` like `onProviderDisabled`.

**But** most of our apps have high "margin" of **backwards compatibility** supporting much older Android versions so you will need to override these ones.

So in order to implement these we can do this by two approaches:

**First** solution is creating a new LocationListener as a variable and implement these methods straight away

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG 1");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG 2");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onProviderEnabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG 3");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onProviderDisabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG 4");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onStatusChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0.5f, locationListener);
```

A **Second** approach is to implement `LocationListener` in your class and implement these methods

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener
```

And now you must implement the methods

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }
```

And your `LocationListener` is your own class

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0.5f, this);
```

Last thing to take in mind is that even tho `public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}` is **deprecated** you SHOULD implement because as i said Android phones that use **Android 9 or lower** are going to trigger that method when taking location updates with `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`

Comment: Why even need to override if source is compiled against compileSdkVersion 30 ?

Answer (score 0):

override the methods in your code

```
...

override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {}
...
```

Comment: Pretty much. If anyone is using Kotlin, don't forget to remove the super calls, or else your default empty implementations will be redundant.