# AbstractMethodError for LocationListener even app built with compileSdkVersion 30

Tags: android, android-location, android-sdk-tools, abstractmethoderror

Below exception is getting thrown for some devices which has Android 9 (API level 28).

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onStatusChanged(java.lang.String, int, android.os.Bundle)"
```

With this cause seems I am missing some fundamental concepts, as per my assumption app shouldn't throw this exception as app built with **compileSdkVersion 30** meaning that we don't need to override default methods defined in `LocationListener`.

Please help me to understand above issue.

If we had to override to avoid above issue then seems issues is with Android SDK.

**EDIT :** Here is the update from Google team

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190695723

Comment: The method was made `default` in Android 11 (API 30). If you compile against API 30 you don't have to provide implementation, but older devices still expect it. This is clearly wrong. You should report this in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312). I expect the solution by Android Team would be to make the compiler generate an empty implementation for us.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Kinda surprised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190695723. I guess they are missing very basic concept about build system.

Answer (score 1):

you use locationListenerCompat,later succesfully

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31378713)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issues is on Android SDK, on Sdk Version 29 below needed to override this.

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the onStatusChanged(), but you can also use the new [LocationListenerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/location/LocationListenerCompat) interface.

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69539440/1797960) answer here for more details.